# How to test whether text color inside text box is changing if user does not provide any data and click on search in selenium (Java)

Tags: java, selenium

Here my scenario is -Verifying text color inside text box if user does not provide any data and directly clicks on search.

> URL :- https://www.seniorhousingnet.com/

I am directly clicking on Search button without entering data in city text box ,in that case color is changing and i need to verify whether color of text is changing or not through selenium (java)

But from html if we observe before click and after click color is same rgb(113, 76, 93)
so developers are handling this through script, in this situation, can anybody explain me how to handle this test case?

Below is my code

```
@Then("Enter city name \"([^\"]*)\" in text field$") 
public void enteringCityNameInsideTextField(String city) throws InterruptedException{

    String functionName="searchBoxToEnterCity";
    if(Driver.WebCtrl.isDisplayed("NewSHN1/HP1", "SearchBoxCity")){
        System.out.println("city is "+city);
        if(city.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            String textColorbefore = Driver.Gprops.GetWebDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("input#searchHomeLocation")).getCssValue("color");
            Driver.WebCtrl.sendKeys("NewSHN1/HP1", "SearchBoxCity", city);

            Driver.WebCtrl.clickOnElement("NewSHN1/HP1", "Search");
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            String textColorafter =  
            System.out.println("text color before is "+textColorbefore);
            System.out.println("text color after is "+textColorafter);
            if(textColorbefore.equals(textColorafter)){
                Driver.CUtil.WriteResults("Functioanlity", "wwithout entering any text directly clicking on search button ", "Failed");

            }
            else{
                Driver.CUtil.WriteResults("Functioanlity", "wwithout entering any text directly clicking on search button ", "passed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: I am still not sure about the color change, but I could see some changes in html if 'Search' is clicked without any data; like class value of `input` element is appended with 'Error'. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks Kamal .It worked .i didn't notice that.:)